# React AntDesign: Calling methods in renders inside the columns

Tags: reactjs, frontend, antd

I'm new in React, I want to designed a page using Ant Design about showing etc. customer infos.
Some infos like product, country are showing their Id's (shown in image below) but I want to show their names. I have methods like getProductById(), getCountryById() but can't call them. I researched and tried several solutions but couldn't solved it.

How can I call my methods in renders inside the columns component or have you another advise?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      getCustomerInfoListPaged({
        identity: appConfig.config.customerId,
      })
    );
  }, [dispatch]);

    const columns: ColumnType<CustomerDto>[] = [
        {
          title: l("Actions"),
          width: 50,
          render: (text, rec, index) => (
            <div>
              <Dropdown
                trigger={["click"]}
                overlay={
                  <Menu>
                    <Menu.Item key={1} onClick={() => handleDeleteClick(rec)}>
                      {l("Delete")}
                    </Menu.Item>
                  </Menu>
                }
              >
                <Button type="primary" icon={<MenuOutlined />}>
                  {l("Actions")}
                </Button>
              </Dropdown>
            </div>
          ),
        },
        {
          title: l("Name"),
          dataIndex: "customerName",
          key: "customerName"
        },
        {
          title: l("Surname"),
          dataIndex: "customerSurname",
          key: "customerSurname"
        },
        {
          title: l("Product"),
          dataIndex: ["productId"],
          key: "productId",
          //render: (text) => (),
        },
        {
          title: l("Country"),
          dataIndex: ["countryId"],
          key: "countryId",
        },
        {},
      ];
    
      return (
        <Card title={l("List")}>
          <div>
            <Form
              id="searchForm"
              form={form}
              layout="vertical"
              autoComplete="off"
              onFinish={onFormFinish}
            >
              {}
            </Form>
          </div>
    
          <Table
            rowKey="id"
            size="small"
            dataSource={customerList?.items || []}
            columns={columns}
            onChange={handleTableChange}
          ></Table>
        </Card>
      );
    };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to trigger an event in each handler, as given [here](https://ant.design/%7Edemos/components-table-demo-edit-cell) also refer code [here](https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-edit-cell).

One caveat can be, if a modification event calls the method in the row itself rather than the parent, it may not updated.